# modify the notification of angularjs pushnotification

Tags: angularjs, cordova, push-notification

I'm trying to add push notification on android using angularjs, cordova and the pushplugin.

I receive the notification, but i want to change the content of the data received before showing the notification of the status bar.
For example i send with the server something like :

Title : i'm coming late
Message : sender 555-555555

Is it possible to change the number with the contact name like WhatsApp?

To have something like :
Title : i'm coming late
Message : sender John Doe

Here is my code:

```
    window.onNotification = function(e) {

    switch( e.event )
    {
        case 'registered':
            if ( e.regid.length > 0 )
            {
                console.log("Your regID is : " + e.regid);
            }
            break;

        case 'message':
            e.message = "message changed";
            // this is the actual push notification. its format depends on the data model     from the push server
            if ( e.foreground )
            {
                alert("foreground alert");
                console.log("foreground log");
            }
            else
            {  // otherwise we were launched because the user touched a notification in the notification tray.
                if ( e.coldstart )
                {
                    alert("cold start notif");
                    console.log("cold start notif");
                }
                else
                {
                    alert("cold start notif nop" );
                    console.log("cold start notif nop");
                }
            }
            console.log('message = '+e.message);
            alert("GCM message received " + JSON.stringify(e.message));
            alert(JSON.stringify(e));
            angular.element(document.querySelector('#yata')).html(e.message);
            break;

        case 'error':
            console.log('GCM error = '+e.msg);
            break;

        default:
            console.log('An unknown GCM event has occurred');
            break;
    }
};
```

with this code the message is correctly changed in the alert box, but when the app is in background or closed the notification received isn't modified.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think that is possible directly from Cordova.

You should implement your own [GcmListenerService](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/gcm/GcmListenerService) to intercept [push messaging events](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/downstream#sample-receive) and then show your custom notification [using the NotificationManager](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidNotifications/article.html#notificationmanager).

Comment: Thanks for your answer, i tried to find some already existing plugin in cordova, but it doesn't seem to exist, i'll try to create one and make it work.